# JSP/MySQL(JDBC) - Select statement is giving empty results

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, jdbc

**JDBC-MySQL driver is properly installed and connection is fully working.**

I have inserted created database, table, inserted rows and from view-data I have executed the select statement. Those worked fine. But in this code, only ***INSERT*** statement is working and adding the result where ***SELECT*** statement is not.
I have no clue also after searching hours on the internet.

Here is the code -

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%

    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "pass");
    if (!connection.isClosed()) {
        out.println("Connection Established");

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users.user_details (`Email`, `Name`, `Password`)  VALUES ('ram@gmail.com', 'Ram Das', '12345678')");
        preparedStmt.execute();
        String sql="select * from user_details";
        PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        } 
    } 
    connection.close();
%>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You used `System.out` instead of out. Is ist printed in the console?

Comment: @SilverNak, lol, thanks, I just overlooked it. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   While(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("Email"));
    }
```

Use while instead of if.

If you are using out.println() you will see output in the browser and if you are using  System.out.println() you will see output in the ide's output window.

Comment: Yeah, I now got that. And +1 for reminding to use "while" because in case of "if", only one result would be displayed.